# Windows Server Hyper-V host Ubuntu guest network down until restart after incident

Tags: ubuntu, networking, hyper-v, connection, netplan

I have a Windows Server 2022 host with Hyper-V installed. There are two Generation 2 VM's installed, Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 LTS servers.

Host machine has a network configuration that looks like this:

[image: /ipconfig /all]

Basically it has a main static IP and 4 more additional IP's attached.

Hyper-V virtual switch is configured as following:

[image: Virtual Switch Manager]

Then I have a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server guest with following netplan configuration:

[image: Ubuntu netplan configuration]

And following Hyper-V guest VM setup:

[image: VM network configuration, page 1]

[image: VM network configuration, page 2]

This VM uses one of additional static IP's available to host.

Everything works as expected until there is a network disconnect for any reason, let it be maintenance work at hoster level, or a DDoS attack that brings network down for 1-2 minutes.

The actual problem is that Ubuntu guest machine remains offline until it is completely restarted. The network configuration does not try to reinitiate and become online again by itself. It simply stays offline forever.

There is a second virtual machine that has exactly the same problem, running Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS, using netplan network configuration exactly the same as previous server, but for next additional IP available.

*There is one very important thing that I should mention*: While Ubuntu guests stays forever offline after any disconnection reason, the host Windows Server always comes back online once connection is back, without need to restart it.

I need help understanding what is wrong, with either my Ubuntu server network configuration, or Hyper-V configuration.

I have changed two different hosters, but the problem remains.

I have tried changing several Hyper-V VM network settings like:

- Protected network checkbox
- Virtual machine queue checkbox
- Changing VM MAC to dynamic

On Ubuntu server I have tried different netplan settings:

- Disabling matching of MAC
- Disabling optional setting

I expect that Internet connection on Ubuntu guest VM will recover after any incident and my public services will get back online, because the machine keeps running as it did, but without Internet connection, unable to access either inbound or outbound.